# Implementing LeCun Local Contrast Normalization with Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I'm trying to use the code that I found to implement the LeCun Local Contrast Normalization but I get incorrect result. The code is in Python and uses the `theano` library.

```
def lecun_lcn(input, img_shape, kernel_shape, threshold=1e-4):
    """
    Yann LeCun's local contrast normalization
    Orginal code in Theano by: Guillaume Desjardins
    """
    input = input.reshape(input.shape[0], 1, img_shape[0], img_shape[1])
    X = T.matrix(dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    X = X.reshape(input.shape)

    filter_shape = (1, 1, kernel_shape, kernel_shape)
    filters = gaussian_filter(kernel_shape).reshape(filter_shape)

    convout = conv.conv2d(input=X,
                             filters=filters,
                             image_shape=(input.shape[0], 1, img_shape[0], img_shape[1]),
                             filter_shape=filter_shape,
                             border_mode='full')

    # For each pixel, remove mean of 9x9 neighborhood

    mid = int(np.floor(kernel_shape / 2.))
    centered_X = X - convout[:, :, mid:-mid, mid:-mid]
    # Scale down norm of 9x9 patch if norm is bigger than 1
    sum_sqr_XX = conv.conv2d(input=centered_X ** 2,
                             filters=filters,
                             image_shape=(input.shape[0], 1, img_shape[0], img_shape[1]),
                             filter_shape=filter_shape,
                             border_mode='full')

    denom = T.sqrt(sum_sqr_XX[:, :, mid:-mid, mid:-mid])
    per_img_mean = denom.mean(axis=[1, 2])
    divisor = T.largest(per_img_mean.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x', 1), denom)
    divisor = T.maximum(divisor, threshold)

    new_X = centered_X / divisor
    new_X = new_X.dimshuffle(0, 2, 3, 1)
    new_X = new_X.flatten(ndim=3)

    f = theano.function([X], new_X)
    return f(input)
```

Here is the testing code:

```
x_img_origin = plt.imread("..//data//Lenna.png")
x_img = plt.imread("..//data//Lenna.png")
x_img_real_result = plt.imread("..//data//Lenna_Processed.png")

x_img = x_img.reshape(1, x_img.shape[0], x_img.shape[1], x_img.shape[2])
for d in range(3):
    x_img[:, :, :, d] = tools.lecun_lcn(x_img[:, :, :, d], (x_img.shape[1], x_img.shape[2]), 9)
x_img = x_img[0]

pylab.subplot(1, 3, 1); pylab.axis('off'); pylab.imshow(x_img_origin)
pylab.gray()
pylab.subplot(1, 3, 2); pylab.axis('off'); pylab.imshow(x_img)
pylab.subplot(1, 3, 3); pylab.axis('off'); pylab.imshow(x_img_real_result)
pylab.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image: Example image processing results]

*(left to right: origin, my result, the expected result)*

Could someone tell me what I did wrong with the code?

Comment: I made something similar once, but unfortunately cannot run your code, because it is not self-contained. Could you make it runnable, and thus debuggable? Among other things you will need to specify which Gaussian filter function you are using.

Comment: Hi eickenberg,

Here is the code, please change the image path as needed.
http://pastebin.com/x6WREp7D

Here is the image:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png

Let me know if you need anything else. I think the threshold is the culprit. If I increase the threshold, it becomes more similar to the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I implemented local contrast normalization as reported in Jarrett et al (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/jarrett-iccv-09.pdf). You can use it as a separate layer.

I tested it on the code from the LeNet tutorial of theano in which I applied LCN to the input and to each convolutional layer which yields slightly better results.

You can find the full code here:
https://github.com/jostosh/theano_utils/blob/master/lcn.py

```
class LecunLCN(object):
def __init__(self, X, image_shape, threshold=1e-4, radius=9, use_divisor=True):
    """
    Allocate an LCN.

    :type X: theano.tensor.dtensor4
    :param X: symbolic image tensor, of shape image_shape

    :type image_shape: tuple or list of length 4
    :param image_shape: (batch size, num input feature maps,
                         image height, image width)
    :type threshold: double
    :param threshold: the threshold will be used to avoid division by zeros

    :type radius: int
    :param radius: determines size of Gaussian filter patch (default 9x9)

    :type use_divisor: Boolean
    :param use_divisor: whether or not to apply divisive normalization
    """

    # Get Gaussian filter
    filter_shape = (1, image_shape[1], radius, radius)

    self.filters = theano.shared(self.gaussian_filter(filter_shape), borrow=True)

    # Compute the Guassian weighted average by means of convolution
    convout = conv.conv2d(
        input=X,
        filters=self.filters,
        image_shape=image_shape,
        filter_shape=filter_shape,
        border_mode='full'
    )

    # Subtractive step
    mid = int(numpy.floor(filter_shape[2] / 2.))

    # Make filter dimension broadcastable and subtract
    centered_X = X - T.addbroadcast(convout[:, :, mid:-mid, mid:-mid], 1)

    # Boolean marks whether or not to perform divisive step
    if use_divisor:
        # Note that the local variances can be computed by using the centered_X
        # tensor. If we convolve this with the mean filter, that should give us
        # the variance at each point. We simply take the square root to get our
        # denominator

        # Compute variances
        sum_sqr_XX = conv.conv2d(
            input=T.sqr(centered_X),
            filters=self.filters,
            image_shape=image_shape,
            filter_shape=filter_shape,
            border_mode='full'
        )


        # Take square root to get local standard deviation
        denom = T.sqrt(sum_sqr_XX[:,:,mid:-mid,mid:-mid])

        per_img_mean = denom.mean(axis=[2,3])
        divisor = T.largest(per_img_mean.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x', 'x'), denom)
        # Divisise step
        new_X = centered_X / T.maximum(T.addbroadcast(divisor, 1), threshold)
    else:
        new_X = centered_X

    self.output = new_X


def gaussian_filter(self, kernel_shape):
    x = numpy.zeros(kernel_shape, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    def gauss(x, y, sigma=2.0):
        Z = 2 * numpy.pi * sigma ** 2
        return  1. / Z * numpy.exp(-(x ** 2 + y ** 2) / (2. * sigma ** 2))

    mid = numpy.floor(kernel_shape[-1] / 2.)
    for kernel_idx in xrange(0, kernel_shape[1]):
        for i in xrange(0, kernel_shape[2]):
            for j in xrange(0, kernel_shape[3]):
                x[0, kernel_idx, i, j] = gauss(i - mid, j - mid)

    return x / numpy.sum(x)
```

Comment: Would be really cool if you also added an example of how to call the function. I am very new to those methods and the result I get from calling LecunLCN is `Elemwise{true_div, no_inplace}.0` and I don't know if it is correct and how to extract the image from it.

Comment: For those like me that do not know anything about theano, the output of the function is an object that as yet to be compiled by evaluating the object. Hence, if you want to extract the convolved image you have to write `LecunLCN(X).output.eval()[0][0]`

Answer (score 1):

I think these two lines may have some mistakes on the matrix axes:

```
per_img_mean = denom.mean(axis=[1, 2])
divisor = T.largest(per_img_mean.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x', 1), denom)
```

and it should be rewritten as:

```
per_img_mean = denom.mean(axis=[2, 3])
divisor = T.largest(per_img_mean.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x', 'x'), denom)
```